# In a transformer, how do you determine where the induced EMFs (E) and voltages (V) are placed in a vector diagram?

Tags: voltage, current, transformer, load, winding

I will be citing pictures from Electrical Technology by Theraja.
So there are different cases with regards to the transformer depending on what losses and loads are considered. Each of them have different vector diagrams. My question is how do you know where to place E1 and E2 as well as V1 and V2? It feels like it's different depending on the case. You will see later in the cases I present that there is no consistent placement of E1, E2, V1 and V2 in all 5 cases.

I want to know how those vectors were made in the vector diagram, and from there I can get how to make the rest since I already have an understanding of the angle relationships between voltage and current.

---

## Case 1 - Ideal Transformer

No losses of any type and no load. 
Taken from Page 1121.

[image]

As you can see, E1 and E2 are in phase. V2 is not shown because probably it is equal to E2 since there is no load.

---

## **Case 2** - Practical No Load Transformer

Has core losses and no load. 
Taken from Page 1126.

[image]

As you can see, E1 and E2 are in phase. V2 is not shown because probably it is equal to E2 since there is no load.

---

## Case 3 - Practical On Load Transformer

Has core losses and load. 
Taken from Page 1129.

[image: ![enter image description here]

What happened to E1 and V2?

---

## Case 4 - Practical On Load Transformer with Resistances

Has core losses and load with winding resistances. 
Taken from Page 1132.

[image]

This one is clearer since E1, E2, V1 and V2 are all present in the diagram. I just want to ask for an explanation why they are placed that way.

---

## Case 5 - Practical On Load Transformer with Resistances and Reactances

Has core losses and load with winding resistances and reactances. 
Taken from Page 1135.

[image]

This one is also clearer since E1, E2, V1 and V2 are all present in the diagram. I also just want to ask for an explanation why they are placed that way.

---

EDIT: I actually noticed that for Case 3 to Case 5, where a Practical Transformer has a load, E1 and E2 have a constant placement in the y-axis. That would probably make things easier to explain to me.

My question is why are those induced EMFs selected as the reference for those cases? Why not the voltages (V)? It might be for convenience or tradition, but I was wondering if there are other reasons besides those if those are one of the reasons.

Then for Cases 1 and 2, why are E1 and E2 in phase with each other and why on the negative y-axis?

Also, (a) (b) and (c) in pictures with 3 diagrams refer to (a) resistive load or 1 pf, (b) inductive load or lagging pf and (c) capacitive load or leading pf.

Comment: My advice is that any consideration of the induced voltage in the primary is of little use when analysing transformers. But, this question is too lengthy for this site IMHO. Focus on your first recent question on transformers as answered by Neil and work on understanding that correctly. Your 2nd recent question is fine but this question (above) is too lengthy and there is no indication from you that you have got those earlier questions answered to your satisfaction. Nobody will want to answer this question if there are doubts about what has sunk in.

Comment: I understand the response about the question length. I guess I will make do with the information, but before accepting an answer I do want to know the answer to why Case 1 and 2 has induced EMFs in the same direction while Case 3, 4 and 5 have opposite direction. What caused the change?

Comment: Case 4 b and c are correct because they have a minus sign in front of E1 but, without knowing what circuit they are considering, it's just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question really seems too long. Anyway ... about this excerpt:

> *My question is why are those induced EMFs selected as the reference for those cases? Why not the voltages (V)? It might be for convenience or tradition, but I was wondering if there are other reasons besides those if those are one of the reasons*.

Using EMF as a reference facilitates the understanding of the influence of the Power Factor on voltage drops and helps to establish the fact that it is only there that the transformer's turns ratio is fully satisfied, regardless of whether the transformer is in no-load or under load.

And about this:

> Then for Cases 1 and 2, why are E1 and E2 in phase with each other and why on the negative y-axis?

I believe it was for convenience, to avoid many overwritten vectors. The fact that the polarity (direction in which the coil was wound) is positive or negative will cause these two vectors (E1 and E2) to have the same or opposite direction.

Comment: Okay. Would like to clarify. I just want this answered, and probably I have accepted how everything else works.
Why does E1 and E2 have the same direction in case 1 and 2 but opposite directions in case 3, 4 and 5? What caused the change?

Comment: In fact, they can have the same direction OR opposite direction. It is just a matter of polarity. Maybe this will help you: https://pressbooks.bccampus.ca/singlephasetransformers/chapter/additive-and-subtractive-polarity/